# Backbone.js - bootstrapping data into collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following data in a variable:

```
[{"age":"65","_id":"526fb6c940301e040e000002","name":{"first":"Jane","last":"Does"},"__v":0,"modified":"2013-10-31T10:03:26.435Z"},{"age":"25","_id":"526fb6c940301e040e000001","name":{"first":"John","last":"Doe"},"__v":0,"modified":"2013-10-31T10:03:26.436Z"},{"age":"45","_id":"526fb6c940301e040e000003","name":{"first":"Alice","last":"Smith"},"__v":0,"modified":"2013-10-31T10:03:26.436Z"}]
```

I am trying to bootstrap my collection with this data.

```
this.collections.staff = new StaffCollection;
this.collections.staff.reset( data , {parse: true} );
```

when I `console.log(this.collection.staff)`, the following is the result:

[image: console.log]

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the collection like this:

```
this.collections.staff = new StaffCollection(data);
```

You can check it working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/CJ5yx/2/).

Cheers.

Comment: I used, but both produce the same result. http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap

Comment: I didn't know about that link, but anyway, now that I'm checking the fiddle it works also with `var staff = new StaffCollection;
    staff.reset(data, {parse: true});`. Have you modified your parse function @Joe?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the following:

```
var json_data = JSON.parse( '{{data variable in String}}' );

this.collections.staff = new StaffCollection( json_data, {parse:true} );
```